# Is it safe to use non unique kafka keys for financial events?

Tags: apache-kafka

We use kafka to send events with financial information. We plan to use account id as kafka key for all events for account will be sent to the same kafka partion and ensure ordering of events for account. Events can be lost in case of compaction but our devops said they carefully review all pull-request for code-based configuration and will not enable compaction of topic on accident. Does it will be safe or we should use some unique id for all events and implement custom partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, keys are for ordering. In particular, keys are not related to fault tolerance.

For not losing message, you should do the following:

**On topic level:**
Set the replicas count to any number will help you sleep better at night (lets say 3 replicas).

**On producer level:**
Set acks to be 'all' (the argument name and value change depending on the client you are using).
This will make sure a message is considered committed only when all replicas saved the data to disk.

**On consumer level:**
Set delivery guarantee to be 'at least once'.
This will make sure you don't lose any data. On the other hand, you might be processing messages more than once, if your code is not idempotent you will have to handle that.